# How to capture heap dump without data in java

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-dump

I've set -Xmx100g for my java program (i have to), now that i suspect of a memory leak in the program, capturing and loading 100GB heap dump takes more than two hours in each iteration (when i change something in code and want to check if it fixed the memory leak by heap dump analysis). Most of the heap is data (for example half of it is Text file content) and i really do not care about object contents while analyzing the heap.

So how can i skip dumping heap data and have the smallest possible heap dump for memory leak analysis (just Object's metadata and not their values)?

Answer (score 1):

If the heap takes too long to dump, reduce the heap size using `-Xmx...`.

If you have a memory leak, it is doubtful that you will need a 100GB heap to find the evidence.  So reduce it.

> So how can i skip dumping heap data and have the smallest possible heap dump for memory leak analysis (just Object's metadata and not their values)?

I don't think it is possible.   Besides, in a lot of cases, it is the values (e.g. reference chains) that allow you / the profiler to identify the origin of leaking objects.

Comment: 60GB of heap would be allocated on application startup, so i can not reduce Xmx

Comment: Well in that case, you will just have to patient ... and wait while the heap is dumped.